# Moving file in git repository

Tags: git, github

In my local repository, I created a new directory and moved a file to it from another location within repository. Now when I do 'git status', git has already staged the file at new location(shown as 'renamed'), and also shows original file as modified.

So now what I am supposed to do?Do I need to do 'git add' for file shown as modified, and then commit?

Comment: Correct, that's the next step.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, just do git add for the file which is shown as modified. Git has Automatically figured out you changed the location, so you can simply add and then commit.